# Creating a complex interactive wheel as a web app

Tags: javascript, svg, charts

How would you do to create a chart like this, interactive (i.e. with links and tooltips), in an HTML page?

[image]

From what I know about SVG I think it's the right direction to take (no Flash anyway), but I'd like to know what would be the path you'd take first in order to have an interactive chart looking like this on a web page.

**I'm not asking for the details but just where to begin to look.** I know JavaScript quite well, but I have never dealt with any SVG libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checkout [d3.js examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery), this [example looks very close](http://wimbledon.prcweb.co.uk/matchtree.html) to your pic.

Comment: I can't find better example to "begin looking"! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I offer to use Raphael library (http://raphaeljs.com/) and if you like to make more complex or using 3d objects you can use webgl with treejs library (http://threejs.org/) .. you can find example and demo for charts or other documents in websites..